# Echo value of PDO query with calculation inside

Tags: php, pdo

I just changed my code from using `mysqli_query` to using `pdo` and now when I try to use `$row[0]` I get a result of undefined offset. How do I get the values from the PDO query?

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$hostname.";dbname=saintfiv_artists", $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)
    FROM royalties
    WHERE DATE BETWEEN '".$date2."' AND '".$date13."'
    GROUP BY DATE 
    ORDER BY DATE ASC");

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
         echo number_format($row[0], 2, '.', '') . ', ';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assoc means that you get an array with the column names, so just use the column names of the table in your array as index. Or just change it to: `$row = $stmt->fetch(FETCH_BOTH)`

Comment: the problem is that I am doing a calculation, so it's a combination of two columns

Comment: You can the use the `As xy` syntax or as i said: `$row = $stmt->fetch(FETCH_BOTH)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PDO you get an array back on fetch so no need for the while loop.  Assuming the two variables in the query are dynamic you should also parameterize them for security.  Try something like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$hostname.";dbname=saintfiv_artists", $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = "SELECT SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)
    FROM royalties
    WHERE DATE BETWEEN :date2 AND :date13
    GROUP BY DATE 
    ORDER BY DATE ASC";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':date2' => $date2, ':date13' => $date13));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($results); die();
```

Comment: the variables are not dynamic and also I just need to return the list of values

Comment: You should see your expected data in the print_r I provided.  Just foreach loop over the results and echo what you need.

Comment: That would be something wrong with your actual query and not with PDO.  Are you sure you want to group by DATE?  I don't have enough information to help you with the actual query but I suggest you work the query out using something like phpMyAdmin or Navicat that lets you interact directly with the database.  Once you have the query correct, then the above pdo should provide you with the array of values you need.

Comment: I got it to work with my original code just using `reset` to access to value of the array

Comment: Michael - just noticed the issue in what I posted.  The fetch needed to be a fetchAll.  I updated.  I suggest you try the code I posted as it is closer to what you usually see in PDO.  Of course that is entirely up to you.  Sorry for my oversight.  See this for more http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php